# First time with Python: TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable, with JSON

Tags: python

```
import json
data = json.load(open("data.json"))

def translateWord(w):
return data(w)
word = input("Enter word: ")
print(translateWord(word))
```

Error
Enter word: Rain

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:/3.Projects/PythonBascis/app.py", line 7, in 
>       print(translateWord(word))   File "D:/3.Projects/PythonBascis/app.py", line 5, in translateWord
>       return data(w) TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

I am getting this when running the above code, and i am not sure how to solve it

Comment: [Please format data/error message as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: Ok, and what's the code supposed to do? Getting rid of the error is easy (comment it out, delete it, etc...), but _fixing_ it requires a bit of explanation about the program.

Comment: The code needs to find "Rain word in data.json and print it  the value "liquid water in the form of droplets that have condensed from atmospheric water vapor and then becomes heavy enough to fall under gravity. "

Answer (score 2):

`data(w)` calls the function `data`. Since data is a `dict`, that won't work. Use dictionary access (brackets instead of parentheses) instead:

```
def translateWord(w):
    return data[w]
```

Comment: Yes, this is accepted, i am watching the tutorial, and the guy had (w), and it worked, mine it doesn't

Comment: @Bokchee88 Can you link to the tutorial? Sure, `data(w)` works just fine if `data` is a callable (e.g. function).